# Leer archivo JSON VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Hola necesitaría pode leer un archivo JSON con esta estructura

{
  "1": {
    "coche": "1",
    "velocidad": "2"
  },
  "2": {
    "coche": "3",
    "velocidad": "4"
  }
}

Esto no me funciona

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fichero As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\prog json\lista.json")
        Dim sJsonObj As JSON_Object
        sJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Object)(fichero)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class JSON_Object
   Public coche As String
Public velocidad As String
End Class
```

Gracias por la ayuda..

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, por favor, lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Cuál es el error que te aparece?